# Append multiple files in a loop with a header from only first file in R

Tags: r

I am running the following loop in R:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  do some operation on these files
  output.file <- 'results.csv'
  write.table(file = output.file, x = MYFILE, append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
}
```

Since all output files have the same header, I want to save only the first one at the beginning and delete all the others. Alternatively, to add a header consequently. With `col.names=FALSE` I have no header at all. How to do this in R?

Comment: `names(output.file)<-"my_header"`?

Comment: You can try `col.names = i==1` inside the loop in the call to `write.table`.

Comment: write.table(file = output.file, x = MYFILE, append=TRUE, col.names= i==1, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t") } like this?

Comment: names(output.file)<- c("a","b", etc etc) is giving me the following error: Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "'names' attribute [15] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: the problem of this one (col.names = i==1) is that I have a header somewhere in the middle because it does not append the files in order...

Comment: How many files? Your loop has only 4 so it might be quicker to combine them all and then write the combined file, e.g. `BIG <- do.call(rbind, list(f1, f2, f3, f4))` and then use write.table on `BIG`.